# Create HTML canvas outside of current window

Tags: html, canvas, popup, html5-canvas

Right now I have a canvas pop-up, but I want it to be separate from the window from which it is originated (it's stuck within the boundaries of the first window, I can only drag it within the first window).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new browser instance with: `window.open(aURL,'name','width=400,height=400')`

**1. Create an html file for your popup**

Put this code into `popupTest.html`:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        window{width:300px; height:150px; }
        body{ background-color: ivory;}
        #canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.font='14px verdana';
        ctx.fillText('I am a popup canvas.',20,50);


    }); // end $(function(){});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**2. Open the popup (popupTest.html) in a new browser instance**

Put this code into `runPopup.html` and open it:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{ background-color: ivory; }
        #canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function(){

        var popupURL='popupTest.html';

        function myPopup(url){
            window.open(url,'myPopup','width=400,height=400,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,copyhistory=no,resizable=yes');
            return false;
        }

        $('#pop').on('click',function(){
            myPopup(popupURL);
            return(false);
        });


    }); // end $(function(){});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id=pop>Open Popup</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Note about opening your popup**

This method requires the user to trigger the popup (eg button-click or anchor-click). If you want to programmatically trigger the popup you must be sure the user has any popup blocker turned off or else your popup will be blocked.